# Get the highest parent id recursively in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, query, recursive

I want to find the uppermost parent ID for each entry. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
ParentID int(11) unsigned,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO t1 (ID,ParentID) VALUES (1,NULL),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3);
```

I intent to get

```
ID     Highest ParentID
1      NULL
2      1
3      1
4      1
```

I planned to create a recursive query (MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.5) by adding a condition to break the recursive when Parent ID is a specific value (e.g., NULL in the above case). I started with

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (ID, ParentID) as (
  SELECT ID,ParentID FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.ID,t2.ParentID FROM t1 t2
  INNER JOIN cte on t2.ParentID = cte.ID
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

but it does not work as I intend, as it gets the next ParentID instead of recursively.

Sample [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=295d31216373ad2cc084673e78f905cc).

Comment: I think @Akina means that you should invert your join condition, so `cte.ParentID=t2.ID`

Comment: @Akina you mean I have to order `path` by length and get the first number from the longest path for each ID? Is it an efficient way?

Comment: @Akina I still don't get it. I just need the highest parent for each ID. For example, `WHERE ID=4`, it should return `1`. I do not see this in your query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte as ( SELECT id, id nextid, parentid 
         FROM t1
       UNION ALL
         SELECT cte.id, t1.id, t1.parentid
         FROM t1
         JOIN cte ON cte.parentid = t1.id )
SELECT Id, nextid RootId
FROM cte
WHERE parentid IS NULL
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=209df940143d3e984d418e49929bd847

Answer (score 2):

A possibility from Akinas cte is

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1
> (
> ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
> ParentID int(11) unsigned,
> PRIMARY KEY (ID)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
>
> INSERT INTO t1 (ID,ParentID) VALUES (1,NULL),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,NULL),(6,5),(7,6);
>
> SELECT * FROM t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ID | ParentID
> -: | -------:
>  1 |     null
>  2 |        1
>  3 |        2
>  4 |        3
>  5 |     null
>  6 |        5
>  7 |        6
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE cte (ID, ParentID, path) as (
>   SELECT ID,ParentID, ID path
>   FROM t1
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT t2.ID,t2.ParentID, cte.path 
>   FROM t1 t2
>   INNER JOIN cte on t2.ParentID = cte.ID
> )
> SELECT ID,MIN(PATH) FROM cte GROUP BY ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | MIN(PATH)
> -: | --------:
>  1 |         1
>  2 |         1
>  3 |         1
>  4 |         1
>  5 |         5
>  6 |         5
>  7 |         5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c1ff63739d52016770c1620a0cd8d5d)*

a  adaption to the first, if the number are not sequentiell, you nned to start with

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1
> (
> ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
> ParentID int(11) unsigned,
> PRIMARY KEY (ID)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
>
> INSERT INTO t1 (ID,ParentID) VALUES (1,10),(10,20),(20,NULL),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,NULL),(6,5),(7,6);
>
> SELECT * FROM t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ID | ParentID
> -: | -------:
>  1 |       10
>  2 |        1
>  3 |        2
>  4 |        3
>  5 |     null
>  6 |        5
>  7 |        6
> 10 |       20
> 20 |     null
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE cte (ID, ParentID, path) as (
>   SELECT ID,ParentID, ID path
>   FROM t1
>   WHERE ParentID IS NULL
>
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT t2.ID,t2.ParentID, cte.path 
>   FROM t1 t2
>   INNER JOIN cte on t2.ParentID = cte.ID
> )
> SELECT ID,MIN(PATH) FROM cte GROUP BY ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | MIN(PATH)
> -: | --------:
>  5 |         5
> 20 |        20
>  6 |         5
> 10 |        20
>  1 |        20
>  7 |         5
>  2 |        20
>  3 |        20
>  4 |        20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d767859103b91d1e85202a2786a0167d)*

Comment: You may want to add that your solution requires that parent(id) < id. For a set of tuples like: `(1,10), (10,NULL), (2,1)` it wont work

Comment: yes, i think the the solution  above should also work

Comment: Yes. You can even simplify that case a bit `WITH ... SELECT ID, PATH FROM cte`